# How to Create IP paramater for alexa skill that uses lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am creating a lambda based Alexa skill, and I need to input an IP address for a server that changes for every user that installs the skill. I know there is an account linking option but I need the IP of the server be inputted when the skill is installed.

How do I do that? and how do I pass those parameters to the lambda function?
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this "IP adress for a server" where should it come from?

- You could ask the user in the first skill invocation for the ip

  - read about intents and slots. The slot should be of type number (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/implement-the-built-in-intents.html)
  - how to know it's the first call? Save userId and a counter for skill invocations
  - how to save? I suppose you run your backend on AWS lambda than you could use a dynamoDB. There is quite a nice feature. Read about the PersistanceAdapter. You can store unique featueres per user (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/manage-attributes.html). In your case you would need to set (setPersistentAttributes ) and save two attributes. The counter and the ip address.
- Or do you need in written form? You could generate an id for the alexa skill userId, let alexa speak the id and the user use this id:

  - log in in your webpage with this unique id
  - configure/add an ip address
  - now your skill backend can lookup the ip adress for the userId

Comment: how do I ask for that IP in the invocation?

Comment: I updated my answer. You could use dialogue confirmation to get automatic dialogue for the confirmation. Play around if it's easier to split the IP maybe in 4 different slots.

Comment: Thanks for updating. How do I save that counter? and the IP? I need it to be unique to each user, and they don't need to say it more then one time.

Comment: OK, and about the form option - How do the form get the user's ID? because that way, I can put all of the inputs with the user ID in a database and use it the next time the skill is called.

Comment: ok thought you are gonna go with option one (collect by voice). 
The form does not need the user id. 
Your first skill invocation: you persist alexaUserID and yourself generatedID. 
Speak the generatedId to the user.
The go the form and save input with generatedId and other stuff (ip).
Because alexaUserId and generatedId is a 1:1 relation it's enought to know one of them.

Comment: I created the form myself, how do I get the ID from the account linking from the Alexa app automatically to the form so I can send it to a backend? The second option is the way I want my skill to work.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: which part? Learn alexa skill basics to speak out a generated id. Read about dynamo db or an other persistence option. Learn to build a website and connect it with your persistance layer. It's a bit hard to help here. Just start with the first step to generate a id, persist it and give it back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Can you initiate the linking request from that external server to the skill instead? Look at the App to App linking feature.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html